# How to create Omega 4 subtheme with new "default" libSass based starterkit?

Tags: theming

I am trying to install omega 4, now at 4.4, which uses liBsass for the default starterkit. 
How do I proceed about this - I understand I need now npm and gulp instead of the previous Ruby stuff required for Omega 4.3?
Everything installs fine, but `drush omega-guard` complains about gemfile (which it should not use, as I understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a lot of problems getting started with the new starterkit. It seems to me as if omega-guard does not yet support the new kit. You can still accomplish the same by running `gulp` in the subthemes directory. This will start the gulp watching process in foreground.

For more information about gulp and the libSass starter kit, I can recommend this post: https://www.drupal.org/node/2537364#comment-10287771

Comment: Thanks for the info. This makes me think about other options for the next projects.